# how to move .swf files to some folder when i build it?

Tags: gulp, bower, zeroclipboard

my app created by [generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp), i load some plugins with bower, and some plugin depend on .swf files, such as zeroclipboard and uploader, and my problem is how to move swf files to * folder when i build this app?

eg:

```
gulp.task('extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/.',
    '!app/*.html'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/*.swf'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
});
```

how to Merger that to one task?

Answer (score 0):

i just add one more task!

```
gulp.task('swf', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/scripts/*.swf'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
});
```

done!!!

Comment: Any idea how to do this with Webpack and Grunt?